# JAX-WS Null Param Not Included in SOAP Request

Tags: jax-ws

My problem is that when sending request from Java generated code via SOAP UI (JAX-WS client), the null params are included in SOAP generated request.

I'm generating soap client from a third party WSDL, so don't have any control over WSDL modification.

Message from Java Generated Client, do not have param which have null values. I have to have empty elements, which are `<authId>` & `<reserved>`

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <BillPayment xmlns="http://action.one.worldnet.org">
        <userName>test</userName>
        <password>testing2</password>
        <AccountNumber>10385699</AccountNumber>
        <amount>0000000002300</amount>
        <tranDate>20130311</tranDate>
        <tranTime>064536</tranTime>
        <bankMnemonic>TIMEPAY</bankMnemonic>
        </BillPayment>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Message from SOAPUI, which have elements whose values are null.

```
<soap:Body>
    <soap:Envelope>"
      <act:BillPayment>
         <act:userName>test</act:userName>
         <act:password>testing2</act:password>
         <act:AccountNumber>9132388</act:AccountNumber>
         <act:authId></act:authId>
         <act:amount>0000000010000</act:amount>
         <act:tranDate>20130311</act:tranDate>
         <act:tranTime>172345</act:tranTime>
         <act:bankMnemonic>THIRDParty</act:bankMnemonic>
         <act:reserved></act:reserved>
      </act:BillPayment>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>"
```

Following is my generated BillPayment class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
```

@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "userName", "password", "accountNumber", "authId", "amount", "tranDate", "tranTime", "bankMnemonic", "reserved" })
@XmlRootElement(name = "BillPayment")
public class BillPayment {

```
@XmlElementRef(name = "userName", namespace = "http://action.wirelessnet.org", type = JAXBElement.class)
protected JAXBElement<String> userName;
@XmlElementRef(name = "password", namespace = "http://action.wirelessnet.org", type = JAXBElement.class)
protected JAXBElement<String> password;
@XmlElementRef(name = "AccountNumber", namespace = "http://action.wirelessnet.org", type = JAXBElement.class)
protected JAXBElement<String> accountNumber;
@XmlElementRef(name = "authId", namespace = "http://action.wirelessnet.org", type = JAXBElement.class)
protected JAXBElement<String> authId;
@XmlElementRef(name = "amount", namespace = "http://action.wirelessnet.org", type = JAXBElement.class)
protected JAXBElement<String> amount;
@XmlElementRef(name = "tranDate", namespace = "http://action.wirelessnet.org", type = JAXBElement.class)
protected JAXBElement<String> tranDate;
@XmlElementRef(name = "tranTime", namespace = "http://action.wirelessnet.org", type = JAXBElement.class)
protected JAXBElement<String> tranTime;
@XmlElementRef(name = "bankMnemonic", namespace = "http://action.wirelessnet.org", type = JAXBElement.class)
protected JAXBElement<String> bankMnemonic;
@XmlElementRef(name = "reserved", namespace = "http://action.wirelessnet.org", type = JAXBElement.class)
protected JAXBElement<String> reserved;

/**
 * Gets the value of the userName property.
 * 
 * @return possible object is {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }
 *         {@code >}
 * 
 */
public JAXBElement<String> getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the userName property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *            allowed object is {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }
 *            {@code >}
 * 
 */
public void setUserName(JAXBElement<String> value) {
    this.userName = ((JAXBElement<String>) value);
}

/**
 * Gets the value of the password property.
 * 
 * @return possible object is {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }
 *         {@code >}
 * 
 */
public JAXBElement<String> getPassword() {
    return password;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the password property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *            allowed object is {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }
 *            {@code >}
 * 
 */
public void setPassword(JAXBElement<String> value) {
    this.password = ((JAXBElement<String>) value);
}

/**
 * Gets the value of the accountNumber property.
 * 
 * @return possible object is {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }
 *         {@code >}
 * 
 */
public JAXBElement<String> getAccountNumber() {
    return accountNumber;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the accountNumber property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *            allowed object is {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }
 *            {@code >}
 * 
 */
public void setAccountNumber(JAXBElement<String> value) {
    this.accountNumber = ((JAXBElement<String>) value);
}

/**
 * Gets the value of the authId property.
 * 
 * @return possible object is {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }
 *         {@code >}
 * 
 */
public JAXBElement<String> getAuthId() {
    return authId;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the authId property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *            allowed object is {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }
 *            {@code >}
 * 
 */
public void setAuthId(JAXBElement<String> value) {
    this.authId = ((JAXBElement<String>) value);
}

/**
 * Gets the value of the amount property.
 * 
 * @return possible object is {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }
 *         {@code >}
 * 
 */
public JAXBElement<String> getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the amount property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *            allowed object is {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }
 *            {@code >}
 * 
 */
public void setAmount(JAXBElement<String> value) {
    this.amount = ((JAXBElement<String>) value);
}

/**
 * Gets the value of the tranDate property.
 * 
 * @return possible object is {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }
 *         {@code >}
 * 
 */
public JAXBElement<String> getTranDate() {
    return tranDate;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the tranDate property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *            allowed object is {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }
 *            {@code >}
 * 
 */
public void setTranDate(JAXBElement<String> value) {
    this.tranDate = ((JAXBElement<String>) value);
}

/**
 * Gets the value of the tranTime property.
 * 
 * @return possible object is {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }
 *         {@code >}
 * 
 */
public JAXBElement<String> getTranTime() {
    return tranTime;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the tranTime property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *            allowed object is {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }
 *            {@code >}
 * 
 */
public void setTranTime(JAXBElement<String> value) {
    this.tranTime = ((JAXBElement<String>) value);
}

/**
 * Gets the value of the bankMnemonic property.
 * 
 * @return possible object is {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }
 *         {@code >}
 * 
 */
public JAXBElement<String> getBankMnemonic() {
    return bankMnemonic;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the bankMnemonic property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *            allowed object is {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }
 *            {@code >}
 * 
 */
public void setBankMnemonic(JAXBElement<String> value) {
    this.bankMnemonic = ((JAXBElement<String>) value);
}

/**
 * Gets the value of the reserved property.
 * 
 * @return possible object is {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }
 *         {@code >}
 * 
 */
public JAXBElement<String> getReserved() {
    return reserved;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the reserved property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *            allowed object is {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }
 *            {@code >}
 * 
 */
public void setReserved(JAXBElement<String> value) {
    this.reserved = ((JAXBElement<String>) value);
}
```

}

Looking for expert advice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not post your WSDL. What I suspect is that your `<authId>` has `minOccurs=0` in the schema definition. I am not sure if you are doing top-down or bottom-up design. If you are using top-down, you can simply add `minOccurs=1` in the WSDL schema definition section. If you are using bottom-up design approach, you can use the below annotation in the web service code

```
@XmlElement(nillable=true, required=true)
String authId;
```

Please note that this annotation requires metro 2.0 (JAXB 2.2) or later.

**Edit based on comments:**

If you can upgrade to JDK 7, it should contain the JAX-WS 2.2. However, if you cannot upgrade the whole JDK for any reason, you can follow the instruction [here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/ramapulavarthi/archive/2009/04/tip_for_using_j.html) to use a feature called [Endorsed Standards Override Mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/standards/) by just upgrading the `jaxws-api.jar` and `jaxb-api.jar` files.

Comment: After adding the above annotation, I'm getting following exception

Comment: Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
com.integration.wireless.BillPayment#authId has mutually exclusive annotations @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement and [at]javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRef
 this problem is related to the following location:
  at [at]javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement(nillable=true, name=##default, required=true, defaultValue=

Comment: As I said, the annotation requires metro 2.0 which includes JAXB 2.2. What web service runtime are you using? Does it support JAXB 2.2?

Comment: Alright, my current runtime is JAX-WS 2.1, so should I upgrade it JAX-WS 2.2.7 latest? and have to include JAXB runtime separately.

Comment: Lan... I removed XmlElementRef and replace with XmlElement(nillable=true, required=true) and it start working. Can you please tell me the different between these two, just for information. I'm really thankful to you.